# how to make camel simple expression work with property placeholder in spring xml

Tags: spring, properties, expression, apache-camel, placeholder

I am trying to using property placeholder in camel route.
I have test.properties which define property: MQ.queuename1=TESTQUEUE.
In camel context, i define placeholder:

```
<camel:camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" >
  <propertyPlaceholder id="camel-properties"  location="file:${web.external.propdir}/test.properties"/>
```

In the route, i use simple expresion to evaluate the property:

```
<choice>
           <when>
                <simple>${in.header.queuename} == '{{MQ.queuename1}}'</simple>
            <bean ref="ExtractOrderContent" method="extractContent"/>
                <to uri="websphere-mq:queue:TESTQUEUE" pattern="InOnly"/>
            </when> 
        </choice>
```

When i run camel, the property file is recognized by camel but it looks like the simple expression doesn't work. Do i miss anything?

Comment: What version of Camel do you use?

Comment: camel version is 2.8.4. I can not upgrade to newer camel due to some constrains with other projects.

Comment: I think it has a bug so {{ }} doesnt work when using < when >

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the properties function from simple (http://camel.apache.org/simple)

```
<simple>${in.header.queuename} == ${properties:MQ.queuename1}</simple>
```

The {{ }} in nested < when > is likely due to a bug, that has been fixed in newer Camel releases.

Comment: Thanks a lot Claus. It works. I have bought your book Camel in Action. That is a great book for camel. Do you have plan for a new version of this book?

Comment: Yeah if Camel keeps becoming more and more popular, and the sales of the current book is still good, then yeah the publisher is likely to agree on a 2nd ed.

Answer (score 2):

From the route configuration that you have provided, It seems that you missed out setting queuename in header. Instead you should use properties component as

`<simple>${properties:queuename} == 'MQ.queuename1'</simple>`

Comment: I have already set the value in the header (sorry for not put that setting in my question above). The camel route is working if i hard code the value ${in.header.queuename} == 'NI'. It only not working when i try to use property place holder.

Comment: i have try your solution: <simple>${in.header.queuename} == 'MQ.queuename1'</simple>. But that does not work.